# Random circuits with google cirq

Tags: simulation, cirq, random-quantum-circuit

For my dissertation I need to **simulate random circuits** and I have been trying to use google Cirq for that. Looking at the documentation I have seen how to create my own circuit and simulate it, but it becomes exhausting and prone to error the fact of creating a circuit for a larger number of quits and to produce as much entanglement as possible.

I thought that Cirq would have any method for generating a random circuit for a given number of qubits, but unfortunately have not found anything like this. Therefore, I was wondering whether there is any tool or anyone who has generated circuits that I could import to use.

Comment: Is [this](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/testing/random_circuit) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cirq does have some methods for generating random circuits, such as [cirq.testing.random_circuit](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/testing/random_circuit) and [cirq.random_rotations_between_grid_interaction_layers_circuit](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/experiments/random_rotations_between_grid_interaction_layers_circuit).

That being said, in my experience, generic random circuit methods almost never do quite exactly what I need. I suspect that, for thesis-level work, you will need much more careful control over the generated circuit than you will get from a method written by anyone except you.

Comment: The first thing I have To do is simulate the circuit, obtain the amplitudes of the wavefunction and use Fourier decomposition to obtain the probability function for sampling the random circuit.
I believe the second method that you wrote is what I am looking for! Thank you so much for it. I was looking for different method names so I will have to be a bit more careful in the future.